# How to go about creating a tooltip that shows-up instantly while animating position and opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

*This is a bit broad, note that I'm not looking for a spoon-feeding solution but a general direction.*

I want to create the following behaviour:

[image: tooltip animation]

1. Tooltip shows instantly, on click.
2. Opacity/position animation starts instantly, until it fades out.
3. Several tooltips can be visible at once (in case two or more buttons are clicked shortly one after another)

I'm looking for a plugin with a similar behaviour, but I only find tooltip plugins with the standard tooltip behaviour. I can try code it myself but **I wondered whether there's already a jQuery plugin that allows this, which I'm not aware of**..

Answer (score 0):

it will be easier to add a fading out animation to any tooltip plugin you have then trying to find one witch suits perfectly your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check my code about tooltip on: [http://jsfiddle.net/kdevpl/eDZKt/]

This works on `mouseover();`, but You can change to `click();`